How to instruct Make to copy the i-th file of a list to the i-th path of another list?
I have two lists, both with N elements:
SRC = a/b/foo  a/b/bar  a/b/moo
DST = a/c/fii  a/c/bir  a/c/mee

Is there a way to set a rule that takes the i-th element of SRC as the prerequisite of the i-th element of DST?
I just need to copy, so what I am thinking of is something like
the_i-th_element_of_DST: the_i-th_element_of_SRC
    cp $< $@

As usual, I would like it not to copy if the destination is updated already.

No, there's nothing like that built-in.  You will have to do some magic.
Here's an example that might work:
# Create an explicit rule for each destination file
$(DST):
        cp $< $@

# Now create a prerequisite relationship between each DST and SRC
# using a recursive user-defined macro

MAKE_PREREQ = $(if $1,$(eval $(firstword $1): $(firstword $2))\
    $(call MAKE_PREREQ,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1),$(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2)))

$(call MAKE_PREREQ,$(DST),$(SRC))

(note I didn't test this)
I believe this will fail if any of the filenames in SRC or DST contain commas.

A recursive macro without a termination rule is hardly going to work -- unless aiming for a segfault.

Correct; fixed.

This should do what you're after: a macro to create a list of 1-based list indices and another to emit a rule for each item in the SRC and DST variables.
# $(call 1toN,list)
1toN = $(strip $(if $(word 1,$1),\
  $(call 1toN,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1)) $(words $1)))

$(foreach I,$(call 1toN,$(SRC)),\
  $(eval $(word $I,$(DST)) : $(word $I,$(SRC)); cp -- $$< $$@))

To test for equal list length, for example:
$(if $(patsubst $(call 1toN,$(SRC)),,$(call 1toN,$(DST))),\
  $(error Lengths do not match: SRC DST))

